# Encrypt hard drive with data without a second hard drive

Tags: partition, encryption, disk-encryption

I have a 4 TB external hard drive (file system is ext4) that is filled with approx. 1 to 2 TB of data. The hard drive is not encrypted, but I'm planning to encrypt it with the same mechanism used to encrypt my internal hard drive (i.e., insert password before mounting to gain access to clear data). However, the data doesn't fit onto any other currently available storage medium. Is it possible to *reliably* encrypt the whole disk without requiring another storage medium?

I thought maybe it would be possible to create a second partition on the hard drive, move all data onto that new partition, then clear the first partition, create a new encrypted partition, move all data back from the unencrypted partition to the new partition, and finally to delete the second partition and extend the encrypted partition to cover the whole disk?

Comment: In principle this should work. But what you will do if something went wrong? Are you ready to lose the data?

Comment: A 2TB HDD is under $70 AUD these days (about $43 USD), or a little more in an external USB drive box.  If your data is at all important to you, then buy one.  As well as being safer, it will be a lot faster than thrashing the read-write heads to first copy and then move all the data from one partition to another.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thanks for your assessment. No, I'm not ready to lose the data. Otherwise, I wouldn't ask here and just try it. So, I better first think about how to backup.